# convert unicode to datetime strptime python

Tags: python, datetime

The format from api google calendar is like '2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00'.

I tried to convert to datetime without success:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%z')
```

Es error I get:

> 'ValueError: time data, '2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%z'

How do I get this code to work?

Comment: Please don't tag spam, this question is purely about date parsing and is completely unrelated to unicode and google.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. I was just not thinking for the moment; to tired maybe.

Comment: We can use %z. There is support

Answer (score 2):

this is because strptime expects for the `%z` format a string that looks like: `+0200` not `+02:00`, i.e.:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-04-26T13:00:00+0200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 26, 13, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))
```

so depending on your context, either you modify the string to fit `strptime()` expectations, or you can use a higher level library to handle your dates. Like [maya](https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya) or [pendulum](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/), that offer very flexible facilities to handle format parsing and relative date management.

```
>>> import pendulum, maya # you need to pip install them
>>> pendulum.parse('2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00')
<Pendulum [2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00]>
>>> maya.parse('2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00')
<MayaDT epoch=1493204400.0>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil), the [parse](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) function will help you out.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse('2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 26, 13, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look in the documentation for [PyTZ](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#installation) and [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), tho external modules that add functionality related to date and time. For instance, with arrow, you can do it pretty easily like this:

```
import arrow

my_arrow_object = arrow.get('2017-04-26T13:00:00+02:00')
my_datetime_object = my_arrow_object.datetime

print(my_datetime_object)
print(type(my_datetime_object))
```

This code prints the obtained timestamp and the type of `my_datetime_object` object, which is a `datetime.datetime`:

```
2017-04-26 13:00:00+02:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Arrow also allows to easily generate "humanized" time strings (like "an hour ago" ou "two months ago"), which can be handy.

Comment: Hi, @prometeu! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.